# Can we save new record in decending order in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Can we save new record in decending order in MongoDB? So that the first saved document will be returned last in a find query. I do not want to use `$sort`, so data should be presaved in decending order.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to above mentioned description ,as an alternative solution if you do not need to use $sort, you need to create a **Capped collection** which **maintains order of insertion of documents** into MongoDB collection

For more detailed description regarding Capped collections in MongoDB please refer the documentation mentioned in following URL

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/capped-collections/

But please note that capped collections are fixed size collections  hence it will automatically flush old documents in case when collection size exceeds size of capped collection

Answer (score 1):

The order of the records is not guaranteed by MongoDB unless you add a `$sort` operator. Even if the records happen to be ordered on disk, there is no guarantee that MongoDB will always return the records in the same order. MongoDB does quite a bit of work under the hood and as your data grows in size, the query optimiser may pick a different execution plan and return the data in a different order.

Comment: So we have to use $sort on find query to sort result? Can we use $sort while saving record?